# LoopTools features

Tags: add-on

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but i'm just wondering what do these LoopTools options do.

[image]

i only understand the Bridge. I don't know how to use the other features.
Would someone mind to help this young scholar on his Blender Learning Quest?

Comment: select a loop, then try them

Comment: Old, but still applies: https://sites.google.com/site/bartiuscrouch/looptools

Answer (score -1):

The one you have selected will flatten the selected verts of a mesh like a sphere, Will give you a flat area.

Also right clicking on the tool will give you the option to go to the manual and explain its use.